Curl - Call endpoints in pairs not one by one
I have my scripts endpoints running on localhost(http://127.0.0.1:5001).
What I have:
What I currently do is calling those scripts (endpoints) one by one in a loop from .bat file (I use windows task scheduler as my environment is windows).
How my .bat files looks now:
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,50) do (
    echo Page number: %%i
    curl -s -o nul --max-time 120 http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-script?pageNumber=%%i
    timeout /t 10
)

This works fine but it always execute one script at a time.
What I need:
I need those endpoints to be executed in pairs.
So e.g. Execute page 1 & 2 at the same time, wait until both ends and then wait 10 seconds. After that again call pages 3 & 4 and wait 10 seconds etc.
Obviously for loop can be incremented by 2
for /l %%i in (1,2,50) do ()

But what ever I try with CURL it always ends up either calling page #1, and wait until it finish and then call page #2. Or calling both but don't wait until both response.
e.g. Here is one of my failed examples:
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /l %%i in (1,2,400) do (
    set /a next=%%i+1
    
    echo Page numbers: %%i and !next!
    
    (curl -s -o nul --max-time 120 http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-script?pageNumber=%%i) & (curl -s -o nul --max-time 120 http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-script?pageNumber=!next!)

    timeout /t 10
)

endlocal

This is probably trivial problem but I stuck here.

You could consider using start.

It seems that is only available on Windows 11 which is unfortunately not my system where scripts are running. :(

start is a command built into cmd.exe, it is, and has been, available for all Windows versions you are likely to encounter, and especially any which have the for command!

What Compo said.  Use the start command.  Have two CURL commands in your FOR loop. The first curl command would use the start command. The second curl command would not.

This problem seems simple, but it has several subtle details that make it complicated to solve. Both processes should be started in parallel via start commands, but then you must wait for both processes to end before proceed to the next pair.
There is a "trick" that allows to solve this problem in a very simple way:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /l %%i in (1,2,400) do (
    set /a next=%%i+1
    
    echo Page numbers: %%i and !next!
    
    (
    start "Curl Odd Page"  curl -s -o nul --max-time 120 http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-script?pageNumber=%%i
    start "Curl Even Page" curl -s -o nul --max-time 120 http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-script?pageNumber=!next!
    )  |  pause

    timeout /t 10
)

endlocal

You can read a further explanation on the method used at this answer
PS - Perhaps the start commands may require cmd.exe this way:
start "Curl Page" cmd /C curl -s -o ... 


Antonio, can't believe I forgot about this.  But I remember using set /p.  Do they both act the same?

@Squashman: Yes. In a first answer I used set /P, but pause looks more appropriate for this case... Any command that waits for input on Stdin would also work...

I already give this answer thumbs up as it seems it will work. However I still have some problem with pageNumber. While logging to comand line it says: "Page numbers: 1 and 2" But when CURL fires actualy request with 1 and "!next!" (as a string not variable)

@Andurit: Use start "Curl Even Page" cmd /V /C curl -s -o ... to start the second page

For some reason it always fire "!next!" as a string instead of even page number.

Did you inserted cmd /V /C as I said? This should work... If not, try this: for %%n in (!next!) do start "Curl Even Page" curl -s -o nul --max-time 120 http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-script?pageNumber=%%n
